# Getting an exception after executing "glBindVertexArray(vao);"

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

This is my code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const int IMAGE_SIZE = 32;

GLFWwindow* window;
GLuint vao;
GLuint vbo;

int initWindow() {
    // Initialize GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        cerr << "Error: Failed to initialize GLFW." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up GLFW window hints for OpenGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    // Create window
    window = glfwCreateWindow(IMAGE_SIZE * 20, IMAGE_SIZE * 20 + 60, "PBM Image", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        cerr << "Error: Failed to create GLFW window." << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    // Create context
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Set color and blendmode
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Create and bind VAO and VBO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao); // Here is the spot where I get the exception
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    return 0;
}

void renderImage(vector<unsigned char> vertices) {
    // Update VBO data
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size(), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // Set vertex attribute pointers
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(unsigned char), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // Unbind VBO and VAO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    // Set up projection matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, IMAGE_SIZE, 0.0, IMAGE_SIZE, 0.0, 1.0);
    // Clear screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Bind VAO
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    // Draw points
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertices.size() / 3);
    // Unbind VAO
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

int main() {
    if (initWindow()) return 1;
    // Here comes the code that generates vector<unsigned char> vertices
    renderImage(vertices);
    getchar();
    // Delete VAO and VBO
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    // Terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

It uses glew to setup opengl and glfw for window handling. After initializing the window it generates `vector<unsigned char> vertices` which renderImage takes in. Afterwards it removes VAO, VBO and terminates GLFW. But it won't even come to that point because it throws the following exception at `glBindVertexArray(vao);`:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0000000000000000 in generator.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.
```

Here are my lib and include settings and folders:

[VC++ Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y8Mm.png)

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7sjJ.png)

[Lib Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA2ia.png)

[Lib x64 Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyc1J.png)

[Include GL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKGT3.png)

[Include GLFW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICzGg.png)

Comment: `0x0000000000000000` is a null pointer.

Comment: @drescherjm so what does that mean in the context of the code?

Comment: It means you probably need to obtain a debugger and find out where it happens. If you have Visual Studio you can break into the debugger at the point of the exception and examine the callstack to determine the line that it happens on by changing the "Stack Frame" on the debug toolbar to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*glew* needs to be initialized (see [Initializing GLEW](https://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)). If glew is not initialized, the OpenGL API function pointers are not set. Call `glewInit()` right after `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)`:

```cpp
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    return 1;
```